# How to show $(N-1)\sigma^2_{N-1}=N\sigma^2_N-\frac{N}{N-1}(Y_N-\mu_N)^2$?

Tags: statistics

> Show that $$(N-1)\sigma^2_{N-1}=N\sigma^2_N-\frac{N}{N-1}(Y_N-\mu_N)^2$$
>   where $\sigma^2_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(Y_i-\mu_N)^2$ and $\mu_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^NY_i.$

Trial: 
\begin{align}
(N-1)\sigma^2_{N-1} &=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}(Y_i-\mu_N+\mu_N-\mu_{N-1})^2\\ &=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}(Y_i-\mu_N)^2+2(\mu_N-\mu_{N-1})\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}(Y_i-\mu_N)+(N-1)(\mu_N-\mu_{N-1})^2 \\&=\left[\sum_{i=1}^N(Y_i-\mu_N)^2-(Y_N-\mu_N)^2\right]+2(\mu_N-\mu_{N-1})(N-1)(\mu_{N-1}-\mu_N)+(N-1)(\mu_N-\mu_{N-1})^2 \\&=N\sigma^2_N-(N-1)(\mu_N-\mu_{N-1})^2 -(Y_N-\mu_N)^2
\end{align}
Here I am stuck.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First
$$
\begin{align}
\mu_N-\mu_{N-1}&=\mu_N-\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}Y_i=\mu_N-\frac{N}{N-1}\mu_N+\frac{1}{N-1}Y_N\\
&=\left(1-\frac{N}{N-1}\right)\mu_N+\frac{1}{N-1}Y_N= \frac{1}{N-1}\left(Y_N-\mu_N\right)
\end{align}
$$
and hence
$$
-(N-1)(\mu_N-\mu_{N-1})^2=-(N-1)\frac{1}{(N-1)^2}(Y_N-\mu_N)^2=-\frac{1}{N-1}(Y_N-\mu_N)^2.
$$
Then the last two terms in your last expression becomes
$$
\begin{align}
-(N-1)&(\mu_N-\mu_{N-1})^2-(Y_N-\mu_N)^2=-\frac{1}{N-1}(Y_N-\mu_N)^2-(Y_N-\mu_N)^2\\
&=-\left(\frac{1}{N-1}+1\right)(Y_N-\mu_N)^2=-\frac{N}{N-1}(Y_N-\mu_N)^2.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is really helpful.

Comment: You're welcome!